# $ keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Tags: java, keytool, rhel7

I'm trying to run the command

```
keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

for listing my java certificates, but gives me below error:

```
keytool error: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 11
```

The `-import` command also throws the same error:

```
keytool -import -alias xxx.xxx.x.x -file /etc/ssl/xip.io/xip.io.pem -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

I'm using Rhel 7.6, openjdk version "1.8.0_181".

Comment: Stack trace please. You might be caught up in the switch from JKS to PKCS#11 format.

Comment: Thanks much @MarquisofLorne Actually my java was corrupted since we had a server shutdown, i re-installed java and working seamlessly.

Answer (score -1):

keytool -v -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts --storepass changeit